# Way to calculate the top x% of users from a database

Tags: python, mongodb, aggregate, pymongo, percentile

I was wondering if there was an actually good way to aggregate/calculate percentiles based on all data in a database. For example, data like:

```
{
'name':'John'
'rank':5
},
{
'name':'John'
'rank':4
},
{
'name':'John'
'rank':5
},
{
'name':'James'
'rank':3
},
{
'name':'Froggy'
'rank':5
},
```

How would I go about finding a way to calculate the percentile that users achieve a specific rarity compared to others. Example: James falls in the top 10% of users who own rank 5.

Comment: You can use `$setWindowFeilds` for that

Comment: @nimrodserok Can you provide an example that relates to this? It'd have to return something along the lines of "This user has more rank five items than 77% of users" or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*emphasized text*You can do something like:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$name",
      rankFiveCount: {$sum: {$cond: [{$eq: ["$rank", 5]}, 1, 0]}}}
  },
  {
    $setWindowFields: {
      sortBy: {rankFiveCount: -1},
      output: {
        rank: {$rank: {}},
        totalCount: {$count: {}}
      }
    }
  },
  {$match: {_id: wantedUser}},
  {
    $project: {
      name: "$_id",
      _id: 0,
      percentile: {
        $round: {$multiply: [{$divide: ["$rank", "$totalCount"]}, 100]}
      }
    }
  }
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/oWQfZx4Zdey)

Comment: This does indeed work, however, is there a way to maybe reduce the amount of stuff being queried to specifically one user (for performance). This will aggregate data for the whole database, not just the one user.

Comment: The way that your schema is defined require calculating all users in order to find the percentage of one user

Comment: You can add a `$match` phase for specific user(s) after the `$setWindowFields`, in order to run the `$project` phase on specific user(s) only

Comment: I added this `$match` to the answer

Comment: Thank you so much, this works perfectly! Exactly what I was looking for, been stuck on this for 2 days haha, appreciate the help

Comment: One last thing, would it be possible to calculate percentiles of percentages. For example, in this data set, I'm looking for a user's percentile for his percentage of rank fives to all ranks he has.

Comment: You can elaborate the query to calculate the users percentile to all ranks, and then calculate the ratio between them.

Comment: Need it user-specific, all *owned* ranks by that user, so in the data above, John's rank 5 percentage would be 66%, and I need to find the percentile that 66% falls in compared to all users'

Comment: In this case, you can do something like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/icw8RV6-n0A)

Comment: I tried messing around with the example you gave, however, it seems that the data seems to be inaccurate for larger datasets. For example, two people with completely different rank 5 percentages can have the same percentile ranking, would this be the result of a rounding error?

Comment: Okay yeah, turns out it was just a rounding error, thank you so much for your help, you are god sent <3

Answer (score 0):

I think the formula for that would be `(no_of_people_with_rank_5/total_people)*100`. And honestly, it also depends about the logic in database, is it that a person with rank 5 holds all other ranks or are the ranks all separate? For this answer I will assume all ranks are separate.

```py
import json

database = json.load(open("Yourdatabasefile.json", "r"))
# Skip above, if you already have the data

def find_userbase_percentiles(database: dict) -> dict[float]:
    # You would ideally want to call this function once.
    frequencies = {}
    for x in database:
        frequencies.setdefault(x['rank'], 0)
        frequencies[x['rank']] += 1
    # Now we have frequencies
    for k, v in frequencies.items():
        frequencies[k] = (v/len(database))*100  # Our percentile formula
    return frequencies

def find_user_qualifications(user: str, rank: int, frequencies: dict) -> str:
    # Modify this function to your requirements
    return f"{user} falls in the top {int(frequencies[rank])}% of users who own rank {rank}"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    freq = find_userbase_percentile(database)
    print(find_user_qualifications("James", 5, freq))
```